# Rails for Zombies - Lab 3 › Exercise 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried solving this exercise for 2 hours and I just can't find a solution?

Anybody, help please?

http://railsforzombies.org/labs/3/exercises/16

The exercise:

> **Objective**
>
> In the each block, if a Zombie has more than 1 tweet, print out SMART ZOMBIE
>
> **Your Database:**

```
Zombies
id  name  graveyard
1   Ash   Glen Haven Memorial Cemetary
2   Bob   Chapel Hill Cemetary
3   Jim   My Fathers Basement

Tweets
id  status                                    zombie_id
1   Where can I get a good bite to eat?       1
2   My left arm is missing, but I don't care  2
3   I just ate some delicious brains          3
4   OMG, my fingers turned green.             1
```

> **The view code:**

```
<% zombies = Zombie.all %>

<ul>
  <% zombies.each do |zombie| %>
    <li>
      <%= zombie.name %>
      # add if statement here
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you paste the exercise? You have to be connected to see it.

Comment: @Intrepidd I couldn't paste it here because the exercise was disordered. But @Brandon already answered my question, so thanks anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code you are looking for is:

```
<% if zombie.tweets.count > 1 %>
SMART ZOMBIE
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It's so simple. I should really review the videos.

Answer (score 0):

Any idea why this wouldn't also work?  I'm trying to make another call to get all Tweets by this zombie.

```
<% t = Tweet.where(:id => zombie.id) %>
<% if t.size > 1 %>
<%= 'SMART ZOMBIE' %>
<% end %>
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
#<ActionView::Template::Error: uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Tweet>
```

Or do you think the tutorial is designed to only work with one solution, and you can't make a call to access the tweets table?

Answer (score 0):

## Original Hint #1

> Use the .size or .count methods to see if the zombie has more than one tweet.

## Original Hint #2

A possible correct answer is:

```
<ul>
  <% zombies.each do |zombie| %>
    <li>
      <%= zombie.name %>
      <% if zombie.tweets.size > 1 %>
      SMART ZOMBIE 
      <% end %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
  <% zombies.each do |zombie| %>
    <li>
      <%= zombie.name %>
      <% if zombie.tweets.size > 1 %>
      <em> SMART ZOMBIE </em>
      <% end %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

[Print Exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dviRK.png)